# Permutations algorithm prints out parts of error message

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to make a permutation algorithm. For some reason it returns parts of error message and I don't understand why and how to stop it.
When I have added another else if statement, the problem disappeared but I'd like to know why.
`

```
function permutations(string) {
  var result = [ ];

  if ( string.length === 0) {
    var error = "nothing to output"; // for some reason it puts one letter into the array
    return error;
  } else if (string.length === 1) { //this loop somehow fixes it?
    return string;
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      var firstChar = string[i];
      var otherChar = string.substring(0, i) + string.substring(i + 1);
      var otherPermutations = permutations(otherChar);

      for (var j = 0; j < otherPermutations.length; j++) {
        result.push(firstChar + otherPermutations[j]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}

console.log(permutations("abc"));
//prints ["abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"] when I add extra loop.
//when I remove extra else if, it prints (102) ["abcn", "abco", "abct", "abch", "abci", "abcn", "abcg", "abc ", "abct", "abco", "abc ", "abco", "abcu", "abct", "abcp", "abcu", "abct", "acbn", "acbo", "acbt", "acbh", "acbi", "acbn", "acbg", "acb ", "acbt", "acbo", "acb ", "acbo", "acbu", "acbt", "acbp", "acbu", "acbt", "bacn", "baco", "bact", "bach", "baci", "bacn", "bacg", "bac ", "bact", "baco", "bac ", "baco", "bacu", "bact", "bacp", "bacu", "bact", "bcan", "bcao", "bcat", "bcah", "bcai", "bcan", "bcag", "bca ", "bcat", "bcao", "bca ", "bcao", "bcau", "bcat", "bcap", "bcau", "bcat", "cabn", "cabo", "cabt", "cabh", "cabi", "cabn", "cabg", "cab ", "cabt", "cabo", "cab ", "cabo", "cabu", "cabt", "cabp", "cabu", "cabt", "cban", "cbao", "cbat", "cbah", "cbai", "cban", "cbag", "cba ", "cbat", "cbao", "cba ", "cbao", "cbau", "cbat", "cbap", …]`
```

Comment: `var otherPermutations = permutations(otherChar);` is a string in case of an error, so now you start iterating... over the `"nothing to output"` string in the `for(var j = 0; ...)`.

Comment: a) permutations of the empty string should be your recursion base case. It's not an error b) if you want to mark an error, you should *`throw` an exception*. Returning a string as if it was a valid result will of course do harm to the unsuspecting caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For some reason it returns parts of error message and I don't understand why

That's because your error message becomes the `otherPermutations` in the caller, and it iterates over its elements (it did expect an array...). Don't `return` errors, `throw` them.

> how to stop it?

You already found a way, a base case for string length 1 (although you better had returned an array). But actually the empty string should be your base case: the result should be an array containing exactly the single empty string.

```
function permutations(string) {
  var result = [];

  if (string.length === 0) {
    result.push("");
  // } else if (string.length === 1) { // not necessary
  //  result.push(string);
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      var firstChar = string[i];
      var otherChars = string.slice(0, i) + string.slice(i + 1);
      var otherPermutations = permutations(otherChars);

      for (var j = 0; j < otherPermutations.length; j++) {
        result.push(firstChar + otherPermutations[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```